# Переименовать имя устройства в телеграм клиенте

Tags: windows, telegram

Речь вот об этом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я знаю, что есть опция переименовать, но меня интересует как я могу на уровне системы изменить эти данные?
Откуда телеграм их берет?
Я думал что телеграм их берет из реестра HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\OEMInformation
Но после того как я изменил информацию там, в самом телеграмме ничего не поменялось...

Answer (score 1):

Телеграмм берёт это значение из

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\BIOS

Параметр **SystemProductName**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. После изменения скинул сеанс с телефона и перезапустил телеграмм на компьютере. Всё сработало.